# How to Improve runtime for Iterative Function

Tags: c#

My codes runtime is getting quite long, it has to iterate maybe 30,000 times and that takes around 30 sec on my computer but longer on the clients. I'm wondering if I can get any tips to speed up the calculations. The iterative functions has to put the value as close to zero as possible and it decreases or increases until the conditions are met. I sped it up by increasing by $1 then when it gets closer to the range it increments by $0.1 for precision.

I Broke it into nodes. There's an initial node, then it checks difference of left node then difference of right node. Which ever produces a smaller difference it goes in that direction until difference is as small as possible.

```
//Current Node
double InitialFinalPayment = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(0);
double intialPaymentAmount = Calc_Payment(Findper() - FindSkipNMonths(), Findnint(),
                                             Findpv() + InterestPaid, Findfv(), Findcf(), Findpf(), Finddisc(),
                                             Findbep()), 2);
double diffInitial = Math.Abs(intialPaymentAmount - InitialFinalPayment);

decimal runningIncrement = 1M;
double nextPayment       = 0;

//Node Ahead
Double incrementOutcome = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(runningIncrement);
Double incrementPayment = intialPaymentAmount       + (double)runningIncrement;
Double diffincrement    = Math.Abs(incrementPayment - incrementOutcome);

//Node Behind
Double decrementOutcome = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(-runningIncrement);
Double decrementPayment = intialPaymentAmount       - (double)runningIncrement;
Double diffdecrement    = Math.Abs(decrementPayment - decrementOutcome);

if (diffincrement < diffInitial)
{
    runningIncrement += 1.0M;
    double nextValue = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(runningIncrement);
    nextPayment       = intialPaymentAmount + (double)runningIncrement;
    double diffNext = Math.Abs(nextPayment  - nextValue);
    while (diffNext < diffdecrement)
    {
         diffdecrement     = diffNext;
         runningIncrement += 1.0M;
         nextValue         = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(runningIncrement);
         nextPayment       = intialPaymentAmount  + (double)runningIncrement;
         diffNext          = Math.Abs(nextPayment - nextValue);
    }
    diffincrement     = diffNext;
    runningIncrement -= 0.01M;
    nextValue         = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(runningIncrement);
    nextPayment       = intialPaymentAmount  + (double)runningIncrement;
    diffNext          = Math.Abs(nextPayment - nextValue);

    while (diffNext < diffincrement)
    {
         diffincrement     = diffNext;
         runningIncrement -= 0.01M;
         nextValue         = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(runningIncrement);
         nextPayment       = intialPaymentAmount  + (double)runningIncrement;
         diffNext          = Math.Abs(nextPayment - nextValue);
    }
    return nextPayment + (double)0.01M;
}

else if (diffdecrement < diffInitial)
{
     runningIncrement += 1.0M;
     double nextValue  = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(-runningIncrement);
     nextPayment       = intialPaymentAmount - (double)runningIncrement;
     double diffNext = Math.Abs(nextPayment  - nextValue);
     while (diffNext < diffdecrement)
     {
         diffdecrement     = diffNext;
         runningIncrement += 1.0M;
         nextValue         = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(-runningIncrement);
         nextPayment       = intialPaymentAmount  - (double)runningIncrement;
         diffNext          = Math.Abs(nextPayment - nextValue);
     }
     diffincrement     = diffNext;
     runningIncrement -= 0.01M;
     nextValue         = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(-runningIncrement);
     nextPayment       = intialPaymentAmount  - (double)runningIncrement;
     diffNext          = Math.Abs(nextPayment - nextValue);

     while (diffNext < diffincrement)
     {
          diffincrement     = diffNext;
          runningIncrement -= 0.01M;
          nextValue         = bruteforceFlexibleAmortization(-runningIncrement);
          nextPayment       = intialPaymentAmount  - (double)runningIncrement;
          diffNext          = Math.Abs(nextPayment - nextValue);
     }
     return nextPayment - (double)0.01M;
     }
return InitialFinalPayment;
}
```

The only idea I have is by increasing/decreasing running increment to be a larger value and making that value smaller as it gets closer to the value. Like how it's 1 then 0.1, maybe 10 then 1 then 0.1 but it's definitely not gonna be clean code

Comment: Well, your bruteforceFlexibleAmortization looks very suspicious by it's name.

Comment: Did you try profiling your method to figure out what part takes so long?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek it's the while statements. When it has to decrease/increase by 1.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a more effective way to do the math involved?

Comment: You should dive deeper. Your `while` loop does a lot of stuff in it. btw. Can you try multiplying/dividing instead of adding/substracting? e.g, start with multiplying by 2. It's too large now? Get in between last 2 values (`(current+lastLower)/2`). Too low now? Get `(current+lastGreater)/2`. Similar to how binary search works. It's really hard to give you anything else by ideas because we don't know what your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: have you considered perhaps refactoring your code in regards to `Loan Amortization` calculations. there are plenty of working code examples / programs out on the web look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766716/loan-amortization-code-calculation as well as do a google search on `Loan Amortization Code Calculation`

Comment: @DJKRAZE This is a calculation method that regular formulas cannot solve, only brute force would be idea for it to get the exact values. The regular amortization methods I already have implemented :P

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek that sounds like a great idea thanks!

Comment: I see.. ok can you perhaps debug the code and see where you can possibly make improvements then.. it's really difficult to give accurate answers without knowing how all of your code functionality works.. sorry

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks anyways DJ Kraze. I definitely understand your point of view, I just wanted to post to see if I can get wonderful opions from stackoverflow as usual =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `bruteforceFlexibleAmortization` is [monotonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) you should try using similar approach that's used by binary search instead of changing your input by the same value all the time.

```
var currentValue = 50;
var lastLower = 0;
var lastGreater = 100;

do
{
    var currentResult = calculateResult(initialValue);

    if(currentResult < expectedResult)
    {
        lastLower = currentValue;
        currentValue = (currentValue + lastGreater) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        lastGreater = currentValue;
        currentValue = (currentValue + lastLower) / 2;
    }
} while (Math.Abs(currentResult - expectedResult) < epsilon)
```

It will be a little different for you, because you need to call 2 methods, but you should get the point.

e.g. If you're trying to interpolate square root for a given `n` to a certain precision using your approach would be really slow. With binary-like you can get much more iterations to get close interpolation.

Comment: btw. let me know how much faster that solution is. I'm quite curious :)